# ¿Como hago para reemplazar los ceros o nulls en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
Esta es mi consulta sin group by


SELECT DISTINCT
  (concat_ws(' / ',r.HoraIni_Hor,r.HoraFin_Hor)) as Hora,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Lunes' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Lunes,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Martes' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Martes,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Miercoles' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Miercoles,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Jueves' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Jueves,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Viernes' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Viernes
FROM horario r
INNER JOIN curso s
  ON r.Curso_Key = s.Cod_Curso

ORDER BY r.HoraIni_Hor ASC

esta es mi consulta con group by

SELECT DISTINCT
  (concat_ws(' / ',r.HoraIni_Hor,r.HoraFin_Hor)) as Hora,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Lunes' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Lunes,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Martes' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Martes,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Miercoles' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Miercoles,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Jueves' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Jueves,
  (CASE WHEN r.Dia_Hor = 'Viernes' THEN s.Nom_Cur ELSE 0 END) AS Viernes
FROM horario r
INNER JOIN curso s
  ON r.Curso_Key = s.Cod_Curso
GROUP BY r.HoraIni_Hor
ORDER BY r.HoraIni_Hor ASC
```

[image: Alli esta el resultado]
(SIN Group by)

osea cuando hago group by solo me muestra ceros o nulls (salvo el dia lunes, que solo en la ultima hora me muestra un cero que deberia ser CYT_I_PRIM) en vez de mostrarme el codigo que deberia ser, y deseo saber como podria hacer para que en mis resultados se muestren los datos correctos en vez de ceros o nulls

ejemplo en la primera hora deberia aparecer **PSOC_I_PRIM** ( ese esta bien), **TUT_I_PRIM, ING_I_PRIM, TUT_I_PRIM, ING_I_PRIM** (estos son los que hacer group by r.HoraIni_Hor solo me muestran ceros (o nulls).

pensé que no habían los resultados, pero si estan, solo que aparecen después de ceros (o nulls)
y lo que busco que se vea los códigos de curso correspondiente a su día y hora.

solo tengo 2 tablas horario y cursos, la PK de este último es la FK en Horario.

disculpen si no me dejo entender bien, es la primera vez que consulto :(

Espero puedan guiarme y gracias por la ayuda que me den :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(CON Group by)